# SharePoint writing content to a site navigation programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

For a certain sub site in sharepoint I want to add a new section to the navigation on the left handside. For example "My Section". Under "My Section" I wish to some links but I want to control the hml output of the links. For example add my own classes. How would I go aboutdoing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two questions here:

1. How to create menu items programmatically. The answer is here: http://itfootprint.wordpress.com/2007/08/07/adding-menu-items-navigation-to-sharepoint-site/
2. How to display the items you have added in a different manner. To do this, you have to customize the ASP.Net code that accesses the QuickLaunch navigation. Hints could be found here:

   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466994.aspx
   - http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/04/26/customizing-the-quick-launch-menu-adding-fly-out-menus-to-sharepoint-navigation.aspx
   - http://www.aarebrot.net/site/index.php/branding/32-customizingthequicklaunchandnavigationbars